# Normalisation issues regarding a relationship

Tags: database, sqlite, database-normalization

I am looking for some guidance regarding a library database I am currently creating.

**The Situation**
I have an ***Accounts Table*** that stores all of the user's information.
I have a ***Books Table*** that stores all of the book's information.
I have a ***MyBooks Table*** that attempts to store the books that a user has taken out from the library.

The user can borrow many books and a book can be borrowed by many users (given that the book is free to be taken).

**My Approach**
Now, the issue is that I believe that my approach to solving this issue is not normalised.\

ERD I designed prior to implementing the database.
[image]

It leads to this within the table, which allows the table to store multiple books that belong to one user.
[image]

However, I have been told there should be a linking table somewhere because the BookID can just keep growing and seems that it could populate the table very fast and make it slower, though I'm not sure if that is true.

Here is my approach when I created the database using sqlite3 in Python 3 and it achieved the results I wanted, but at a possible cost of normalisation?

```
from sqlite3 import connect

conn = connect('LibrarySystem.db')
c = conn.cursor()


c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Accounts (
            user_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            email_address NVARCHAR(320) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            password VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            staff_mode INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            my_booksID INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            FOREIGN KEY(my_booksID) REFERENCES MyBooks(my_bookID)
            )""")
conn.commit()


c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Books (
            bookID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            author VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            genre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            issued INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            FOREIGN KEY(genre) REFERENCES Genres(genre)
            )""")
conn.commit()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE MyBooks (
            my_booksID INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            bookID INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            date_issued TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            return_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            FOREIGN KEY(bookID) REFERENCES Books(bookID)
            )""")
conn.commit()
```

Is there any normalisation issues regarding my approach?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the table `Accounts` there is a column `my_booksID` referencing `my_booksID` of `MyBooks`. Why?
Do you plan to have a new row in `Accounts` for the same user every time they take a book?

Instead, you should have a column `user_id` in `MyBooks` referencing `user_id` in `Accounts`.
This way you make `MyBooks` the *linking* table between `Accounts` and `MyBooks`.

When a user takes a book out from the library, you will add a new row in `MyBooks` with the `user_id` of the user and the `bookID` of the book.

Also, in SQLite there are no `VARCHAR` and `TIMESTAMP` data types (check [Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)).
In the case of `VARCHAR` use `TEXT` and for `TIMESTAMP`, if you want to store dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD` (which is the only valid date format for SQLite) use `TEXT`, or if you want to store dates as unix timestamps use `INTEGER`.